# Estoy experimentando un alto consumo de memoria RAM al generar mis reportes CSV

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo una aplicación en Spring Boot que crea archivos  CSV y he notado que después de generar los reportes, la aplicación sigue consumiendo memoria RAM. Aunque estoy escribiendo más de 300,000 registros en el archivo CSV, no he podido identificar la causa exacta del consumo de memoria. He intentado actualizar las librerías, monitorear el consumo con la herramienta JConsole y asegurarme de que todas las conexiones se cierren adecuadamente para evitar fugas de memoria. El consumo alto de memoria se debe al gran número de registros, pero esperaría que el consumo disminuya después de la generación del reporte. Adjunto una imagen que muestra el consumo de memoria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]